# How to make a code DRY without repeat, PHP

Tags: php, laravel

i wondering how i can make it simpler...
the thing is

```
if($results['experience'] == 0) { loadViev('experience',$experience, $careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
if($results['Education'] ==  0) { loadViev('Education',$graduate,$careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
if($results['Extra'] == 0)      { loadViev('Extra',$extra,$careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
if($results['Licence'] == 0)     { loadViev('Licence',$licence,$careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
if($results['Cert'] == 0)        { loadViev('Certyfikaty',$cert,$careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
if($results['conferences'] == 0){ loadViev('Conferences',$conferences,$careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
if($results['Courses'] == 0)    { loadViev('Courses',$Courses,$careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
if($results['Hobbys'] == 0)  { loadViev('Hobby',$hobby,$careerGoals,$mainSectionLines); }
```

As you can see, if some `"name" == 0` function will run, there is for now around 14 combination, i know there is possible to do it faster than copy and paste whole code 14 times...

**result code**:

```
$results =[];
foreach ($userChoice as $key => $value) {
  $setVal = $value['key'];
  $results[$setVal] = $value['order'];
}
```

Result only grab name of a section and order nr. 
'`$userChoice`' is just a array with data

Do anybody have a idea how i can do it?
Also the thing is result collect all the section data (14 section) where as you can see i need only selected 8.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is the word being loaded and the name of the variable. The word remains the same, but the variable is lowercase.

As such, all you would need to do is `loadViev` the `$setVal` name (the word itself) as the first argument, and `$$setval` as the second. This executes the word as a variable, making use of [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Unfortunately you can't (easily) use something like `strtolower()` on a variable variable directly, so you'll have to convert these to lowercase independently first.

This can be seen in the following:

```
$results =[];
foreach ($userChoice as $key => $value) {
  $setVal = $value['key'];
  $results[$setVal] = $value['order'];
  if ($value['order'] == 0) {
    $lower = strtolower($setVal);
    loadViev($setVal, $$lower, $careerGoals, $mainSectionLines);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a few outliers; it's not quite 1:1. You've got `Hobbys`, `Hobby`, `$hobby` (3 different cases), and `Education`, `Education`, `$graduate` (2 different cases), etc. I'd lean towards this approach as well, but the data is a little off :)

Comment: Yes, I was looking to add `strtolower()`, but that doesn't seem to work with variable variables. Bear with me :)

Comment: It _should_. The syntax is wonky: `$test = "ONE"; $one = "TWO"; dd(${strtolower($test)});` (results in "TWO"). I guess `${strtolower($setVal)}` in your case.

Comment: i think this i a best solution but... for now code will be repete 14 times xD also :D
but, i can map throught result and sort data from smallest and after thet just go for loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a structure holding relevant values and iterating over it?

```
$mapping = [
    ['key' => 'experience', 'view' => 'experience','data' => $experience],
    ['key' => 'Education', 'view' => 'Education','data' => $graduate],
    ['key' => 'Extra', 'view' => 'Extra','data' => $extra],
    ...
    ...
];


foreach ($mapping as $m)
{
    if ($results[$m['key']]==0) 
    {
        loadViev($m['view'], $m['data'], $careerGoals,$mainSectionLines);
        break; 
    }
}
```

if you can make your key/variable names consistent, you could simplify the code even further. E.g.

```
$validKeys = ['experience', 'education', ... ];

foreach($validKeys as $k)
{
    if($results[$k] == 0) 
    {
        loadviev($k, $$k, $careerGoals,$mainSectionLines)
    }
}
```